# Laravel 4.2 generates new CSRF token depending of requests frequecy?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, garbage-collection, csrf

I've encountered strange behavior of CSRF token in Laravel 4.2. - token was changing between requests (not always, but randomly).

First thought was that I had problems with garbage collection or there was some bug in Laravel. And even more - this happens only on remote server and locally everything is OK. However, server settings and session config is the same.

Garbage collection in `php.ini` is turned off. The only GC that works is the one started by cron every 30 minutes, however, that also does not relate to this problem - I've checked.

1) If I send ajax requests not frequently (e.g. one time every second) - it works during hours without problems.

2) When I send ajax requests very often during small period of time (20 times during 3-5 seconds) - the token is changed after 15-th or 20-th request. Sometimes even on the 10-th.

Is there some hidden functionality (I did not found that, however) that changes token if it looks like 'dangerous' requests, checking frequency?

Comment: I am having a similar problem, did you find an answer?

Comment: No, I did not. Just something strange.

Comment: Can you check if the token fails to validate and a new one is created in it's place ?

Comment: Did the answer below help you with your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is because the Laravel file session driver does not provide locking. I would suggest switching to the database session driver in `app\config\session.php` and see if you get the expected result.

Here are the relevant docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#session-drivers